# dealing with missing data in R when creating new variables

Tags: r, missing-data

Sorry for the miscommunication before. I have updated my question and hopefully, it's clear now.

I have a data frame. I want to create a variable `ZZ` when any of the `aa`, `bb`, `cc` for the same `ID` is not missing and equals `1`, return `1`; when `aa`, `bb`, `cc` are not missing and they all equal `0`, return `0`; when all `NA`s, return `NA`. Each `ID` only has one `ZZ` value across different rows, either `1`, `0` or `NA`.

For example for the `ID` ∈ {`1`, `2`, `3`} below, I want `ZZ <- c(0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1)`.

#### Input

The reprex...

```r
df <- structure(list(
    ID = c(1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3),
    aa = c(NA, 0, NA, NA, NA,  1, NA, NA),
    bb = c(NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    cc = c(NA, 0, NA, NA, NA,  1,  0,  0)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -8L)
)
```

...and the visualization.

```
  ID aa bb cc
1  1 NA NA NA
2  1  0  0  0
3  1 NA NA NA
4  2 NA NA NA
5  2 NA NA NA
6  3  1 NA  1
7  3 NA NA  0
8  3 NA NA  0
```

#### Goal

The reprex with `ZZ`...

```r
structure(list(
    ID = c(1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3),
    aa = c(NA, 0, NA, NA, NA,  1, NA, NA),
    bb = c(NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    cc = c(NA, 0, NA, NA, NA,  1,  0,  0),
    ZZ = c(0,  0,  0, NA, NA,  1,  1,  1)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -8L)
)
```

...and the visualization with `ZZ`.

```
  ID aa bb cc ZZ
1  1 NA NA NA  0
2  1  0  0  0  0
3  1 NA NA NA  0
4  2 NA NA NA NA
5  2 NA NA NA NA
6  3  1 NA  1  1
7  3 NA NA  0  1
8  3 NA NA  0  1
```

Comment: It might help to clarify your desired result. You mentioned the end result for patient ID 1 should be 0 for all 5 rows...does this reflect that aa, bb, and cc were 0 for two of the rows, ignoring the other rows with missing data? And if all of 5 rows and all 5 columns were NA (25 NAs) then AA should be equal to 5 NAs for those 5 rows for ID 1?

Comment: Also, did you intend to have `ID` included in your data.frame?

Comment: @Ben Yes what you said was 100% correct! I have ID in my data frame

Comment: I ran your new data.frame with the code in my answer below and get the same result as goal.

Answer (score 0):

The `pmax` function can do exactly what you describe in your definition. However, your example is not consistent with it, as you said you expected `AA<-c(0,0,0,0,0)`, but in your example the result based on your definition should be `c(0,0,NA,NA,NA)`.

Here are a couple of example:

```
pmax(aa,bb,cc, na.rm = TRUE)
[1]  0  0 NA NA NA

pmax(c(1,0,NA),c(0,0,NA),c(0,0,NA), na.rm = TRUE)
[1]  1  0 NA
```

In the second case you get `1` in the first index because you have `1` in the first entry of the first element, `0` in the second index because the second index of all three items is `0` and `NA` in the third index because all items have `NA` as the last element.

For completeness, creating the result on a data.frame:

```
aa <- c(0,0,1,1,NA)
bb <- c(0,0,NA,0,NA)
cc <- c(0,0,NA,0,NA)

df <- data.frame(aa,bb,cc)
df %>% mutate(AA = pmax(aa, bb, cc, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: thank you! My question was correct, because it all belongs to one patient, so I want the overall value across the 5 rows. AA<-c(0,0,0,0,0)

Answer (score 0):

This part `!any(AA_pre==1)& any(AA_pre==0)~0,` in your code is self-contradictory. Also, note that `any()` looks at the entire vector. If any value is 0 in the vector, it will return a single logical and mutate the entire `AA` column accordingly. If you want to return the result only for a single row, consider `rowwise()`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(AA_pre = case_when(if_any(c(aa,bb,cc))==1~1,
                            if_all(c(aa,bb,cc))==0~0,
                            .default=NA)) %>%
#  rowwise() %>% #uncomment just in case.
  mutate(AA = case_when(any(AA_pre==1)~1,
                        any(AA_pre==0)~0,
                        .default = NA))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure your intention, but looking at your last question, thought this might be helpful.

First, I added row numbers to the data.frame, so that "all zero" could be considered for a given row.

Then, I put the data into long form, given that IDs can span multiple rows. I add an indicator if a row has "all zero" to be used in the `case_when` which checks first, if all are missing, second if any value in any column is 1, and then third, if any row had all zeroes. Including `.by = ID` will evaluate this across rows for a common ID.

Finally, the data is reverted back to wide form. With better knowledge of original data structure and final desired output, there may be alternative strategies for recoding the data.

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  mutate(rn = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(ID, rn)) |>
  mutate(all_zero = all(value == 0), .by = c(ID, rn)) |>
  mutate(AA_pre = case_when(
    all(is.na(value)) ~ NA,
    any(value == 1, na.rm = TRUE) ~ 1,
    any(all_zero) ~ 0,
    .default = NA
  ), .by = ID) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, rn, AA_pre), names_from = name, values_from = c(value)) |>
  select(-rn)
```

**Output**

```
     ID AA_pre    aa    bb    cc
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1      0     0     0     0
2     1      0     0     0     0
3     1      0    NA    NA    NA
4     1      0    NA    NA    NA
5     1      0    NA    NA    NA
```

**Edit**: With revised post and example data, you should get the same result as goal (just added `relocate` below to put `AA_pre` column last):

```
df |>
  mutate(rn = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(ID, rn)) |>
  mutate(all_zero = all(value == 0), .by = c(ID, rn)) |>
  mutate(AA_pre = case_when(
    all(is.na(value)) ~ NA,
    any(value == 1, na.rm = TRUE) ~ 1,
    any(all_zero) ~ 0,
    .default = NA
  ), .by = ID) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(ID, rn, AA_pre), names_from = name, values_from = c(value)) |>
  select(-rn) |>
  relocate(AA_pre, .after = last_col())
```

**Output**

```
     ID    aa    bb    cc AA_pre
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1    NA    NA    NA      0
2     1     0     0     0      0
3     1    NA    NA    NA      0
4     2    NA    NA    NA     NA
5     2    NA    NA    NA     NA
6     3     1    NA     1      1
7     3    NA    NA     0      1
8     3    NA    NA     0      1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution with [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org).

```r
library(dplyr)


# ...
# Code to generate 'df'.
# ...


df %>%
  # Take the data for each ID...
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    # ...test if it is exclusively NA...
    XX = all(if_all(aa:cc, is.na)),
    
    # ...and extract the numeric maximum where possible.
    XX = if_else(XX, NA, max(across(aa:cc), na.rm = TRUE))
  ) %>%
  # Reset the format.
  ungroup() %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Given your **Input**...

```r
df <- structure(list(
    ID = c(1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3),
    aa = c(NA, 0, NA, NA, NA,  1, NA, NA),
    bb = c(NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    cc = c(NA, 0, NA, NA, NA,  1,  0,  0)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -8L)
)
```

...the output should match your **Goal**:

```
  ID aa bb cc XX
1  1 NA NA NA  0
2  1  0  0  0  0
3  1 NA NA NA  0
4  2 NA NA NA NA
5  2 NA NA NA NA
6  3  1 NA  1  1
7  3 NA NA  0  1
8  3 NA NA  0  1
```